# Chrome extension - loading file from localhost to content_scripts

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm developing Chrome Extension and I need to load a javascript file to content scripts, but that file is being served via webpack-dev-server. So it's approachable only on localhost.

I tried to change my manifest.json:

```
"content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "http://*/*",
        "https://*/*"
      ],
      "js": [
        "http://localhost:3000/scripts/content_bundle.js"
      ],
      "run_at": "document_end",
      "all_frames": false
    }
```

But then I got an error in Chrome Extensions window:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only local files can be specified in `"content_scripts"` section.

Solution:

- add `"permissions": ["http://localhost:3000/scripts/*", "tabs"]` to manifest.json
- download the script using XMLHttpRequest (there are many examples) in your [background script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages) (or better [an event page script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages)) when needed
- save it in `chrome.storage.local` or `localStorage` (so you can load it on every extension start from the storage without redownloading)
- inject the script:

  - add a [tabs.onUpdated](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#event-onUpdated) listener and inject the script using [tabs.executeScript](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-executeScript)
  - alternatively use [declarativeContent](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declarativeContent) API with `RequestContentScript` action (despite the warning on the doc page it should be actually supported in the Stable channel but of course do some tests first).

Comment: Thanks. And what would you recommend for background script?

Comment: @LadislavMaxa, it should contain the code that actually does the things listed in the answer.

Comment: @wOxxOm Interesting approach, I've not seen it documented anywhere. How would you incorporate hot reloading upon changes in the injected .js script? Or does your solution already account for that?

Comment: Hot reloading is an unrelated task. This answer in a few words is "download and execute the script".